# Regex to print lines and count the words

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

So I have the following list as an example.

```
   text = ['Hi my name is Jackson. Hello. Hello my name is Sofia.',   'Hi Sofia, Hello!',   'hello Jackson',   'hi',   'hi, Hello123', 'hi', 'Helllo, HeLlo']
```

And the following code

```
def func(y):    
    counter = 0
    for x in text:
        z = '\b{y}\b'
        if z in text:
          print(x)
          counter +=1 
        return counter
```

Where x should be [Hh]ello
and counter is the number of times.

Desired Output:

func(hello)

> 'Hi my name is Jackson. Hello. Hello my name is Sofia.'

> 'Hi Sofia, Hello!'

> 'hello Jackson'

> counter = 4

Any Ideas?

Comment: No, I have no idea what you are trying to do or what problem you have encountered.

Comment: Are you asking "how to test if a string contains 'hello' or 'Hello'" *and* "how to count the items in a list matching a condition"?

Comment: There is a collection of typos here.

Comment: You have to actually use the `re` module.  `z in text` won't find `\bhello\b` ever.  Try `re.search`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of small issues and typos here:

- To use a variable inside a string, use an f-string, `fr'\b{y}\b'`. Note `r` is there to make `\b` a word boundary, and not a BACKSPACE char
- To test if there is a regex match in a string, use `re.search`, not `in`
- Your data assumes you need a case insensitive match, use `re.I` flag
- Mind the string currently tested in your `func` is `x`, not `test`
- Define the pattern outside a loop, since it is static (you may even use `re.compile`)
- Fix indentation on the `return` line

This is the fix:

```py
import re
text = ['Hi my name is Jackson. Hello. Hello my name is Sofia.',   'Hi Sofia, Hello!',   'hello Jackson',   'hi',   'hi, Hello123', 'hi', 'Helllo, HeLlo']
def func(y):    
    counter = 0
    z = fr'\b{y}\b'
    for x in text:
        if re.search(z, x, flags=re.I):
            print(x)
            counter +=1 
    return counter

print(func('[Hh]ello'))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9QriVK). Output:

```py
Hi my name is Jackson. Hello. Hello my name is Sofia.
Hi Sofia, Hello!
hello Jackson
Helllo, HeLlo
4
```

Comment: Hi great solution, but is anyway to do func(hello) or func(Hello) and achieve the same result, how can I automate re?

Comment: @bot2 Define a variable `hello` and pass to `func`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/gtIhHb). `re` is not automated, it is used to search for/replace/split texts with regex.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I meant it like a string 'hello'

Comment: @bot2 Please share your demo link and point at the exact trouble.

Comment: what does the flag mean the re.I?

Comment: @bot2 Case insensitive matching.